# odoo v9 enterprice saas connecting with xml-rpc

Tags: python, ssl, xml-rpc, odoo-9

I was trying to access my saas online server via xml-rpc but i keep getting the following error:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake    self._sslobj.do_handshake()ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

My simple xml-rpc script:

```
import xmlrpclib
url = 'https://myodoo.com'
db = 'myodoo'
username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
print common.version()
```

And the interesting part is that if i use my saas online **test-myodoo.odoo.com** instance it works but on the main (myodoo.com) one i got the error above.

Do you guys have any idea what could be the cause of the error above?

Any help and suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Teewux

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly OPENSSL related issue i guess.
Upgrade your openssl to version: 1.0.1
Then your script should work :)

tried with installed openssl version=1.0.1 on system and yeahh it is working!